# Add '.'(periods) after text using css

Tags: html, asp.net, css, css-selectors

I have created an ASP page in which I am displaying events. I have used css to display maximum 3 lines of content in one item template.

I want to display 3 periods after the text i.e. :

[image]

I searched over the internet and found solution to add periods after the text using `.after{content:"..."}` but the dots are placed in new line but I want to get the exact output as it is in image.

My css is:

```
        .eventDescription
        {
        height: 45px;
        margin-left: 65px;
        font-size: 15px;            
        line-height: 1.5em;
        overflow: hidden;
        text-align: justify;
        line-height: 15px;
        padding-top: 10px;
        width: 220px;            
        }
```

Comment: There is *some* native browser support for ellipsis (not really the same as three periods): http://mattsnider.com/css-string-truncation-with-ellipsis/

Comment: @TiesonT. Some developers don't use ellipsis, as they already limit the content from server side, but to indicate that the content has still more to read, they prefer this approach :)

Comment: You should specify the relevant HTML and explain whether you expect to truncate the text with CSS (the setting `overflow: hidden` suggests that you might). You should also describe exactly what you tried. The code `.after{content:"..."}` does not do that – there is no class `after` mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 4):

Use `:after` pseudo along with `content` property

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/8zrAv/)

---

You can control the dots spacing, or size using `font-size` and `letter-spacing` property respectively.

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/8zrAv/1/)

---

Coming to your syntax, you are using `.after{content:"..."}` so first of all you need to assign class to the element here, so it will be `<p class="after">` and also you need to add `:after` pseudo to your `.after` class

```
.after:after {
   content: "...";
}
```

> Note: Using `:after`, the content will be `inline` by default, inorder
>   to apply margins or paddings you need to use `inline-block;`, also, older versions of IE won't respect this property.

For more information on browser support for [`:after`](http://caniuse.com/css-gencontent)

Comment: Thank you sir, I modified my css like [this](http://pastebin.com/b9sjxU56) but I am getting output like [this](http://i.imgur.com/lQXOMy4.png).

Comment: @RiyazKalva can you provide your HTML?

Comment: @RiyazKalva can you please provide a fiddle? Could be a `margin`/`padding` or `display:block` issue.

Comment: @RiyazKalva wrap your text using `p` element, like this http://jsfiddle.net/LUmCe/

Comment: I tried your way but it displays only 3 dots it removed the description.

Comment: I created separate class like, `.eventDescription p:after
       {
            content: "...";
       }`

am I doing right?

Comment: @RiyazKalva yes, and than add `p` tags inside `eventDescription` div and wrap the text inside `p`

Comment: @RiyazKalva it's private

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38386/discussion-between-riyaz-kalva-and-mr-alien)